# ListView items are hidden

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have `ListView` with grouped items and when I scroll to bottom of page some items just disappear. It looks like that it is happening only when some part from `HeaderTemplate` is still visible on screen because if I see only items (when I put there more items) then it is absolutely fine.
[image]
Sample: http://1drv.ms/1ARgNre

**Collection of items**

```
<CollectionViewSource
     x:Name="Groups"
     IsSourceGrouped="True"
     ItemsPath="Items"
     Source="{Binding Groups}" />
```

**HeaderTemplate**

```
<ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock
                Foreground="Black"
                FontSize="40"
                Text="Title" />

            <Rectangle
                Grid.Row="1"
                Fill="Gray"
                Height="500" />

            <TextBlock
                Grid.Row="1"
                FontSize="20"
                Foreground="White"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Text="Sample text in header template"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.HeaderTemplate>
```

**GroupStyle**

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock  
                    Foreground="Black"
                    Text="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

**ItemTemplate**

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid
            Background="LightGray"
            Height="100"
            Margin="0,12,0,0"
            Width="300">

            <TextBlock
                Foreground="Black"
                Text="{Binding Title}" />

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I had the exact same behavior. Even MSDN support could not bring up a solution. My fix was to make sure if the Listview Content is bigger than its own hight plus the header hight.

Comment: @KaiBrummund Can you describe it in details please what exactly you mean? btw: if I use StackPanel instead of ItemsStackPanel in ItemsPanel then it works but I am losing some functionality...

Comment: I added a footer that has minheight = listview.height - listviewcontent.height (pseudo code, but I hope you get the idea)

Comment: @KaiBrummund So it means that you put there just "empty place"? It will not look good in my case...

Comment: Yes exactly. I fill up the space, that would otherwise be used by items (if there were more).